# Powershell Remove duplicate entries based on unique column ID in CSV

Tags: powershell

Very new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a CSV file that I need to find and remove columns with duplicate ID's in a specific column. See below:

**Current State of CSV**

```
Fish1,123456,123456 
Fish2,234567,234567 
Fish1,999999,999999
Fish2,234567,234567
```

**Needed State of CS**

```
Fish1,123456,123456
Fish2,234567,234567
```

Essentially regardless of the data in columns 2 and 3 I need to remove all records that are duplicates in column 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to post the code you have so far.

Comment: I'm at a basic level so hope this makes sense.

`code` $MyCoolStuff = Import-Csv C:\path
`code`$MycoolStuff | Sort ID -unique | Out-file C:\path.csv

Basically i have over a million rows with 16k or so duplicated, if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Sort-Object CmdLet to make sure there are no duplicates.

```
Get-Content .\csvfile1.csv | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" | 
    Sort -Unique -Property Column1 | 
    % {"{0},{1},{2}" -f $_.Column1, $_.Column2, $_.Column3} | 
    Set-Content csvfile2.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Jower. Works great. One problem. How do you keep the the first row (the headings)?

Comment: I apologize. I see the headings are there but they are not on top (first row). How do you make it not sort the first row but to just write it to the new file?

Comment: Jower don't waste time finding a solution. Found a way by removing the -Header "Column#",...  Changed Set-Content to Add-Content and having a Set-Content before the Get-Content. There is probably an easier way but works for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a hashtable to keep track of what rows you've already seen:

```
$seen = @{ }
Get-Content -Raw -Path my.csv |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Column1','Column2','Column3' |
    Where-Object { -not $seen.ContainsKey( $_.Column1 ) ; $seen[$_.Column1] = $true; }
```